# Python script to use coordinates from one file and add values from matching coordinates in another file

Tags: python, dictionary, bioinformatics, genome

I have an original set of genomic coordinates (chrom, start, end) in a tab delimited bed file. I also have additional tab delimited bed files that contain some of the original genomic coordinates plus a numerical value associated with each of these coordinates. These coordinates can show up multiple times in a bed file with a different numerical value each time. I need a final bed file that contains each of the original genomic coordinates with the summed number of all the values found to be associated with that specific coordinate. Examples of files I'm working with are below.

**Original File:**

```
chr1    2100    2300

chr2    3300    3600

chr1    2560    2800
```

**Other Bed file:**

```
chr1    2100    2300    6

chr2    3300    3600    56

chr1    2100    2300    10
```

**Needed Output file:**

```
chr1    2100    2300    16

chr2    3300    3600    56

chr1    2560    2800    0
```

I need to write a python script to do this, but I'm not really sure what the best way to do it is.

Comment: Welcome to so! -) If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def fetch_data(filename1, filename2):
    lines = []
    data = {}
    with open (filename1) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        data[' '.join(line.split())] = 0

    with open (filename2) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        arr = line.split()
        data[' '.join(arr[:-1])] += int(arr[3])

    return data


with open ('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for key,value in fetch_data('original.txt','data.txt').iteritems():
        f.write('{0}    {1} \n\n'.format('    '.join(key.split()), str(value)))
```

Comment: Im getting KeyError: 'chr1 2100 2300' from the line data[' '.join(arr[:-1])] += int(arr[3])

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those things that Pandas makes really easy:

```
import pandas
coordnames = ['Name', 'x', 'y']
f1 = pandas.read_table('file1', delimiter=r' +', 
                       names=coordnames).dropna()
f2 = pandas.read_table('file2', delimiter=r' +', 
                       names=coordnames + ['n']).dropna()
result = (f1.merge(f2, on=coordnames, how='left')
          .groupby(coordnames).sum().fillna(0))
```